# Organizing source code in python

Tags: python, package

I am writing a game framework. Here is my current file structure:

```
src/
  framework/
    __init__.py
    util.py
    render.py
    game.py
  pong.py
```

I want to be able to simply do `import game` or `import render` directly from the `pong.py` file. What's the best way to accomplish this? Initially the `util.py, render.py, game.py` modules were in the `src` folder but I decided to put them into their separate folder for the sake of organization.  I am quite new at packaging conventions so I don't know if this would be the recommended way of doing things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way to do this would be not to do it at all. For exactly the reasons you moved them in the first place - the sake of organization - you'll want them to be in a separate module. If you want to refer to the module as `game` in your code, you can do this:

```
from framework import game

game.foo()
```

Generally, when you do `import game`, you are providing the expectation that `game` is either a system library or in the folder the script is running at. If that isn't the case, it will throw people off. If you were to make your framework a system library, you wouldn't have it as three separate libraries `util`, `game`, and `render`, no? You'd package it in one library - `framework` - and distribute that, with submodules. Thus you're really not going to want to do this.

But, as I know non-answers can be frustrating, if you really want to go ahead you can add the `framework` folder to `sys.path`, which python checks whenever you import a module:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("framework")

import game
```

Comment: Would `from framework import *` work? I know it's not recommended but I was reading some stuff about the `__all__` variable that can be defined in `__init__.py` so I'm not sure.

Comment: @Lanaru: try this: in your `__init__.py`, put in `import game; import render; import util;`, and i think then `import *` will work.